# Como capturar o texto de divs aninhadas de forma elegante?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, área-de-transferência

[Este post](http://filipeteixeira.com.br/blog/2015/09/04/como-copiar-texto-para-area-de-transferencia-usando-o-zero-clipboard-2/) explica como copiar texto simples para a área de transferência usando o [ZeroClipboard](http://zeroclipboard.org/).

Porém um leitor trouxe uma dúvida: como pegar o conteúdo de uma `<div>` com várias divs filhas dentro dela? Quando usamos o exemplo acima estritamente falando, um monte de espaço é transmitido (os *tabs* do código fonte).

Como solucionar esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não tenho como testar o ZeroClipboard pois não possuo Flash no meu computador, mas vou arriscar uma resposta visto que a dúvida é mais relacionada a captura de texto e manipulação do que a biblioteca em si.

Como essa biblioteca fornece uma API que te possibilita copiar o conteúdo posteriormente com a função [`setData()`](https://github.com/zeroclipboard/zeroclipboard/blob/master/docs/api/ZeroClipboard.md#zeroclipboardsetdata), primeiro obtenha o conteúdo do elemento (removendo os espaçamentos) e depois chame essa função com o "resultado limpo" do elemento.

```js
(function(){
  
  // Retorna o conteúdo textual do elemento.
  function text(el){
    return el.innerText || el.textContent || '';
  }
  
  // Remove as quebras de linhas da string.
  function clean(str){
    return str.replace(/\r?\n/gm, ' ');
  }

  
  var elemento = document.getElementById('foo');
  
  var conteudo = text(elemento);
  alert('ANTES:\n\n' + conteudo);
  
  conteudo = clean(conteudo);
  alert('DEPOIS:\n\n' + conteudo);
  
  // copia 'conteudo' para o clipboard.

})();
```

```html
<div id='foo'>
  Mussum Ipsum, cacilds vidis litro abertis.
  <div>
    Casamentiss faiz malandris se pirulitá.
    <div>
      Si num tem leite então bota uma pinga aí cumpadi!
      <p>
        Quem num gosti di mum que vai caçá sua turmis!
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: **OFF:** Utilize o [clipboardjs](https://clipboardjs.com/) ao invés do Zero, caso não precise suportar navegadores antigos.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta rápida. Não conhecia essas biblioteca, vou dar uma olhada nela depois.